# Why does the function return the result ahead of time?

Tags: swift

In appDelegate I will check whether the user is authorized through the `userAuthorizedCheck()` function. Depending on the result, redirect it to one or another stroyBoard. `userAuthorizedCheck()` should return the result only after the server has answered. The problem is that if i leave the last `completion(false)` in `userAuthorizedCheck()`, then it returns false first, and then it is checked. Even if the check was successful, then all the same, `completion(false)` is sent first and, as a result, the redirect is sent to the Authorization storyboard.

But if I remove the last `completion(false)`, then I get `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`, opposite func application (). `print (tempToken)` is triggered after checking userAuthorizedCheck (). If i put a breakpoint, i can see that in the `userAuthorizedCheck ()` function, the last `completion (false)` works first.

AppDelegate:

```swift
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        var storyboardName: String = ""
        userAuthorizedCheck(after: { (succesful) in
            if (succesful == true){
                storyboardName = "Main"

            }else{
                print(false)
                storyboardName = "Authorization"

            }
        })


        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: Bundle.main)
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window!.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()

        return true
    }

    func userAuthorizedCheck(after completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        let username : String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "username") ?? ""
        let password : String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "password") ?? ""
        let tokenSaved : String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token") ?? ""
        var tempToken:String = ""


        //
        if(!username.isEmpty && !password.isEmpty)
        {
            let json: [String: String] = ["username": username, "password": password]


            login(json: json, after: {(status, token, code) in
                if(code == 200 && !token.isEmpty){
                    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(token, forKey: "token");
                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
                    tempToken = token
                    print(tempToken)
                    completion(true)

                }
                else{
                    tempToken = ""
                    completion(false)

                }
            })

        }
        else
        {
            completion(false)
        }
        completion(false)//The problem in this line, as I repent

    }
```

login(in another swift file):

```swift
func login(json:Any, after completion: @escaping (Bool, _ token: String, _ code:Int)  -> Void){
    guard let url = URL(string: ngrok+"/api/auth/token/create")else{return}
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")

    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])else {return}
    request.httpBody = httpBody
    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5.0
    sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60.0
    URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig).dataTask(with: request){(data, response, error) in
        if  error != nil{
            print("server error")
            completion(true, "", 0)
        }
        else if let response = response{
//            print(response)
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse{
                guard let data = data else{return}
                do{
//                    print(data)
                    if(httpResponse.statusCode == 200){
                        if let json_response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])as? [String:Any]{
                            if let token = json_response["auth_token"]{
                                print(token as! String)
                                completion(true, "token",httpResponse.statusCode)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if(httpResponse.statusCode == 400)
                    {
                        completion(true, "",httpResponse.statusCode)
                        print("The username or password you entered is incorrect")
                    }
                    else{
                        print("Unknown error")
                        completion(true, "", 0)
                    }
                }
                catch{
                    print("errasd")
                    print(error)
                    completion(true, "", 0)
                }
            }
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

I want the user `Authorized Check ()` function to send the result only after the server has responded.

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/you-cant-use-a-value-after-it-has-been-set-by-asyncronous-code/

Comment: Actually you should start by reading http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot *wait* in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` for something asynchronous before returning `true` or `false`.

One option is to return `true` and load the storyboard after the response of the server

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    userAuthorizedCheck(after: { (succesful) in
        let storyboardName = succesful ? "Main" : "Authorization"
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: Bundle.main)
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window!.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
    })

    return true
}
```

And delete this line in `userAuthorizedCheck`

```
completion(false)//The problem in this line, as I repent
```

because it completes immediately which is not intended.